# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 63: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, utf-8

So I have a dataset in a .json file, I have opened it in python then I want to get data from it. I do some replacement over various strings I don't want, like removing HTML formatting etc.
THen I write the string sentences out to a file.

The problem is I am getting the unicode error.

I have solved it by using

```
mystring=mystring.encode('utf-8')
```

before printing / writing to file, but when I open it in another python script I now get the similar encoding errors when making comparison over strings.

How do I solve this in a somewhat elegant way?

I have found similar issues, but nothing Json related, I read upon it and the json library should implicitly output unicode.

Here is the segment where i Open the json file

```
with open("JEOPARDY_QUESTIONS1.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    for item in json_data:
```

Edit: writing to file

```
result=result.encode('ascii','ignore')
#removing stuff from string
result+='\n'
if i < 40000:
    i+=1
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print "adding question #:"+str(i)
    #this write is throwing the unicode error when the encoding line is not there
    f1.write(result) # this used to be print >> f1,result ( and '\n' wasn't added
```

When I am working with the file the next time I get:

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments     to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

Comment: @KasraAD AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @KasraAD Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsondata.py", line 15, in <module>
    json_data = json.load(json_file.encode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @KasraAD: you gave the OP the *file loading API*. You meant `json.loads()` (with an `s`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters . ah , yes ! i omitted the `s` ,  thanks for reminding !

Comment: @Kameegaming as Martijn mentioned try `json_data = json.loads(json_file.read().encode('utf-8'))`